# JQuery Animate scrollTop lags on Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate, lag

I created a little script that scrolls the page to the position of an element:

```
function scrollToElm(elm){
    $('html,body').clearQueue();
    $('html,body').stop();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: elm.offset().top},500);
}
```

It works perfectly well on Firefox and even Explorer, but in Chrome it is extremely slow, at least on my computer I can't see the animation.

Any ideas why?
Thanks.

Comment: there are tons of reasons why it could be lagging... so you might have to get creative. Is there other javascript firing at the same time? Is the page graphically heavy or does it, in general, load a lot of files?

Comment: not really, the thing is that in Firefox and explorer it works perfectly well, only chrome, here is a sample: http://medusa.mxphosting.com/fullscreen.php

Answer (score 0):

check your browser version. This works 100% fine for me. I am on windows 8 alienware.

Comment: The issue would more then likely reside in threading. To animate to scroll to the top you would have to open up a thread, if a thread is already running this could cause major problems. any other issues regarding lag is sorely your end and not the browser or jquery.